# TSQL PRINT statement conversion issue

Tags: t-sql

When I try to print a line with `int` and `nvarchar` in a single line I get an error. Here's the entirety of my code.

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT, @CONST INT
SET @COUNT = 0
SET @CONST = 12

WHILE(@COUNT<12)
BEGIN
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
    PRINT @COUNT + N' times ' + @CONST + N' is ' + @COUNT*@CONST
END
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' times ' to data type int.

I can print 'int' a `nvarchar` just find on their own, but when I combine them I get this error. Am I improperly combining them?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should `CAST` your variables as nvarchar first:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT, @CONST INT
SET @COUNT = 0
SET @CONST = 12

WHILE(@COUNT<12)
BEGIN
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
    PRINT CAST(@COUNT as nvarchar) + N' times ' + CAST(@CONST as nvarchar) + N' is ' + CAST(@COUNT*@CONST as nvarchar)
END
```

Comment: Ahh, I had my suspicious about casting. Thank you :]